# React native error: Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

> **ERROR**  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.

Check the render method of `BrandWrapper`.

This Error is popping up after upgrade react0-native from 0.68 to 0.71

This is BrandWrapper component and it is called from other component

BrandWrapper.tsx

```
    import GscLogo from 'common/assets/svg/app_logo.svg'
    import GscLogoFr from 'common/assets/svg/app_logo_fr.svg'
    import { LocalizationContext } from 'common/components/Translations'
    import React, { useContext } from 'react'
    import Type from '../Type'
    import AnimatedBlueShape from './AnimatedBlueShape'
    import AnimatedGreenShape from './AnimatedGreenShape'
    import {
      BlueShapeView,
      GreenShapeView,
      ImageView,
      StyledView,
      VersionView,
    } from './styledComponents'
    import { displayJellyBeans as displayJellyBeans } from '../../../../app.json'
    import { displayName as displayName } from '../../../../app.json'
    
    export interface BrandWrapperProps {
      version: string 
      hideVersion?: boolean
    }
    
    /**
     * Component to display branded view with animated shapes
     *
     */
    const BrandWrapper = ({version, hideVersion}: BrandWrapperProps) => {
      const { appLanguage } = useContext(LocalizationContext)
      const dispNameWithoutSp = displayName.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '')
    
      return (    
        <StyledView>
          {displayJellyBeans === true && (
            <BlueShapeView>
              <AnimatedBlueShape />
            </BlueShapeView>
          )}
          <ImageView testID={`splash_image_logo_${dispNameWithoutSp}`}>
            {appLanguage === 'en' ? <GscLogo /> : <GscLogoFr />}
          </ImageView>
          {displayJellyBeans === true && (
            <GreenShapeView>
              <AnimatedGreenShape />
            </GreenShapeView>
          )}
          {!hideVersion && (
            <VersionView>
              <Type bold>Version {version}</Type>
            </VersionView>
          )}
        </StyledView>    
      )
    }
    
    export default BrandWrapper
```

Login.tsx

```
    import VersionCheck from 'react-native-version-check'
    import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info'
    import { Alert, Button, BrandWrapper } from 'common/components'
    //import BrandWrapper from 'common/components/BrandWrapper'
    import IDCardButton from 'common/components/IDCardButton'
    import { LocalizationContext } from 'common/components/Translations'
    import { withBioAuth } from 'common/hoc/withBioAuth'
    import { BioAuthProps } from 'common/interfaces/Biometrics'
    import { getStoreAndPersistor } from 'common/store'
    import { setLoggedIn, setLogout } from 'common/store/slices/auth/auth'
    import { idCardSelectors } from 'common/store/slices/idCard/idCard'
    import { themeSpacing } from 'common/style/theme'
    import JailMonkey from 'jail-monkey'
    import React, {
      useCallback,
      useContext,
      useEffect,
      useMemo,
      useState,
    } from 'react'
    import { Platform, View } from 'react-native'

    import {
      LoginButtonView,
      StyledView,
      TextButtonsContainer,
    } from './styledComponents'
    import { handleOpenLink } from 'common/helperFunctions/navigationHelpers'

    import { get } from 'lodash'
    import { AlertProps } from 'common/components/Alert'
    import { InAppBrowser } from 'react-native-inappbrowser-reborn'
    import {
      androidAppId,
      iOSBundleId,
      registerRedirectScheme,
    } from '../../../../app.json'


    import PopupControllerInfoIcon from 'common/components/PopupControllerInfoIcon'
    
    const APP_ID = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? iOSBundleId : androidAppId
    const REGISTER_REDIRECT_URI = `${registerRedirectScheme}://register`
    
    const Login = ({
      showBioAuthLogin,
      showBioAuthFailed,
      acknowledgeBioAuthFailed,
      biometricPrompt,
      biometricLogin,
    }: BioAuthProps) => {
      
    
    
      return (
        <StyledView testID="screen_login">
         
          {!!alertProps && <Alert {...alertProps} />}
          <BrandWrapper hideVersion={true} version=""/>
          {showIdCardButton && <IDCardButton addSafeAreaTopMargin={true} />}
        </StyledView>
      )
    }
    
    export default withBioAuth<BioAuthProps>(Login)
```

The above code is calling the component and getting the above exception.

Please help with this.

Comment: I believe you are import it wrong.

try to import like that:

`import BrandWrapper from 'common/components/BrandWrapper'`

Comment: Yes I tried that way also. but I am getting same error message

Comment: I am getting compile error on styled component. Is the above error is due to that?

import { GSCTheme } from 'common/interfaces/StyledComponentsTypes'
import styled from 'styled-components/native'

Getting an error on second line after upgrade react native

Comment: @daniel.sousa Can you help with this. 
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77827997/react-jsx-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-components-or-a-c