# react.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, types, components

your text@daniel.sousa Actual Problem is with the ICON Component
Component is not returning an ICON Image but it is returning Number

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.

Please help to resolve this issue

It is as Below. This component is based on the name returns a svg file component. But with upgrade now it is returning number. Implementation is as follows...

```
@daniel.sousa Actual Problem is with the ICON Component
It is as Below. This component is based on the name returns a svg file component. But with upgrade now it is returning number. Implementation is as follows...
----------------ICON.TSX
import React from 'react'
import { gscIcons } from 'common/assets/icons'
import theme from 'common/style/theme'
import { GSCIconTypes, MaterialIconTypes } from 'common/interfaces/IconTypes'
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
import { AccessibilityRole, ImageResizeMode } from 'react-native'
import { IconProps } from 'react-native-vector-icons/Icon'
// * See README for info on how to use this component + add new icons to app

export interface Props extends Omit<IconProps, 'name'> {
  name?: MaterialIconTypes | GSCIconTypes
  size?: number
  width?: number
  color?: string
  gscIcon?: boolean
  resizeMode?: ImageResizeMode
  isSVG?: boolean
  accessible?: boolean
  accessibilityRole?: AccessibilityRole
  accessibilityLabel?: string
  strokeColor?: string
  importantForAccessibility?: any
}

const Icon = ({
  name = 'MED_ITEMS_CAT',
  size = 24,
  color = theme.colors.primary,
  strokeColor,
  gscIcon = false,
  accessibilityLabel,
  accessibilityRole = 'button',
  importantForAccessibility,
  ...rest
}: Props) => {

  console.log(`gscIcons[name] - ${gscIcons[name]}`)

  const isGSC =    
    (gscIcon && gscIcons[name as GSCIconTypes] !== undefined) || gscIcons[name as GSCIconTypes] !== undefined
  if (isGSC) {
    const SVGIcon = gscIcons[name]
    // color prop will only work when fill="currentColor" set inside SVG for path
    return (
      <SVGIcon
        accessible={true}
        accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        importantForAccessibility={importantForAccessibility}
        height={size}
        fill={color}
        stroke={strokeColor}
        color={color}
        {...rest}
      />
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <MaterialIcon
        accessible={true}
        accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
        importantForAccessibility={importantForAccessibility}
        accessibilityRole={accessibilityRole}
        name={name}
        size={size}
        color={color}
        {...rest}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

### Modified GscIcons.tsx is as follows which i imported above
import { gscIcons } from 'common/assets/icons'.

```
 GSC Icons - Member Details
import member_since from './Member_Since.svg'

import add_claims from './Add_Claim_Details_Active.svg'
import add_claims_inactive from './Add_Claim_Details_Default.svg'
import select_provider from './Select_Your_Provider_Active.svg'
import select_provider_inactive from './Select_Your_Provider_Default.svg'
import submit_claim from './Submit_Claim_Active.svg'
import submit_claim_inactive from './Submit_Claim_Default.svg'
import verify_information from './Verify_Your_Information_Active.svg'
import verify_information_inactive from './Verify_Your_Information_Default.svg'

// GSC Icons - Status
// -- little icons
import approved from './Approved.svg'
import declined from './Declined.svg'
import Unknown from './Unknown.svg'
import in_progress from './in_progress.svg'
import attention from './Attention.svg'

// GSC Icons - Main Categories
import CHIRO_TREATMENT from './Chiropractic.svg'
import DRUG_CAT from './Drug.svg'
import EMERG_HOSP_HOME_CAT from './Emergency_Hospital_Homecare.svg'
import FOOT_CARE_CAT from './Footcare.svg'
import HEARING_CAT from './Hearing.svg'
import MASSAGE from './Massage.svg'
import LAB_TEST_CAT from './Medical_Imaging_Testing.svg'
import MED_ITEMS_CAT from './Medical_Supplies_Equipment.svg'
import MENTAL_HEALTH_CAT from './Mental_Health.svg'
import OTHER_SPEC_SERV_CAT from './Other_Special_Services.svg'
import ACUPUNCTURE from './Paramedical.svg'
import PHYSIOTHERAPY from './Physical_Therapy.svg'
import SPENDING_CAT from './Spending_Accounts.svg'
//TODO - replace it with specific image for category
import OTHER_SRVCS_CAT from './Other_Special_Services.svg'
import VISION_CAT from './Vision.svg'
import DENTAL_CAT from './Dental.svg'

// GSC Icons - SubCategories
import accupuncture from './Accupuncture.svg'
import ambulance from './Ambulance.svg'
import athletic from './Athletic_Therapy.svg'
import blood_monitor from './Blood_Monitoring.svg'
import blood_test from './Blood_Tests.svg'
import body_brace from './Body_Braces_Casts_Mobility_Aids.svg'
import breathing_equipment from './Breathing_Equipment_Supplies.svg'
import chiropodist from './Chiropodist.svg'
import counselling from './Counselling.svg'
import dental_services from './Dental_Services.svg'
import dietician from './Dietician_Services.svg'
import drug_pill from './Drug.svg'
import estimate from './Estimate.svg'
import eye_exam from './Eye_Exams_Tests.svg'
import glasses_contacts from './Glasses_Contact_Lenses.svg'
import health_care_spending_acct from './Health_Care_Spending_Account.svg'
import hearing_aids from './Hearing_Aids_Ear_Plugs.svg'
import hearing_exam from './Hearing_Exams_Tests.svg'
import homeopathy from './Homeopathy.svg'
import hospital_room from './Hospital_Rooms.svg'
import in_home_nursing from './In-home_Nursing_Support_Services.svg'
import medical_cannabis from './Medical_Cannabis.svg'
import naturopathy from './Naturopathy.svg'
import nursing_home_ltc from './Nursing_Home_Long_term_Care.svg'
import occupational_therapy from './Occupational_Therapy.svg'
import orthodontics from './Orthodontics.svg'
import orthotics from './Orthotics_Shoes_Shoe_Inserts.svg'
import osteopathy from './Ostheopathy.svg'
import other_diagnostic_tests from './Other_Diagnostic_Tests.svg'
import other_supplies from './Other_Supplies_Equipment.svg'
import personal_spending_acct from './Personal_Spending_Account.svg'
import podiatrist from './Podiatrist.svg'
import speech_therapy from './Speech_Therapy.svg'
import warning from './warning.svg'
import x_ray from './X_ray_Ultrasound_MRI.svg'
import other_specialist_services from './Other_Specialist_Services.svg'

// GSC Icons - Coverage
import coverage_booklet from './Coverage_Booklet.svg'

import success from './success.svg'
import failure from './failure.svg'
import pending from './pending.svg'

// Claim history
import filter from './Filter.svg'

//Dashboard
import payment from './payment.svg'
import health_provider from './Health_Provider.svg'
import form from './form.svg'

// General UX icons
import Icon_Checkbox_Deselected from './Icon_Checkbox_Deselected.svg'
import Icon_Checkbox_Selected from './Icon_Checkbox_Selected.svg'
import right_chevron from './Right_Chevron.svg'
import question from './Question.svg'
import gsc_download from './Download.svg'

// Navigation Icons
import dashboard_fill from './dashboard_fill.svg'
import dashboard_outline from './dashboard_outline.svg'
import claims_fill from './claims_fill.svg'
import claims_outline from './claims_outline.svg'
import coverage_fill from './coverage_fill.svg'
import coverage_outline from './coverage_outline.svg'
import profile_fill from './profile_fill.svg'
import profile_outline from './profile_outline.svg'
import search_fill from './search_fill.svg'
import search_outline from './search_outline.svg'

import Chiro from './Chiropractic.svg'
import Physio from './Physical_Therapy.svg'
import Massage from './Massage.svg'
import MI from './Medical_Supplies_Equipment.svg'
import Orthodontic from './Orthodontics.svg'
import Podiatry from './Podiatrist.svg'
import Acupuncture from './Paramedical.svg'
import Speech from './Speech_Therapy.svg'
import Chiropody from './Chiropodist.svg'
import Naturopathy from './Naturopathy.svg'
import Psychology from './Other_Supplies_Equipment.svg'
import Dental from './Dental.svg'
import Osteopath from './Ostheopathy.svg'
import Audiologist from './Other_Supplies_Equipment.svg'
import Athletic from './Athletic_Therapy.svg'
import Dietician from './Dietician_Services.svg'
import Homeopath from './Homeopathy.svg'
import Occupational from './Occupational_Therapy.svg'
import Drug from './Drug.svg'
import MasterOfSocialWork from './Other_Supplies_Equipment.svg'
import SocialWorker from './Other_Supplies_Equipment.svg'
import Vision from './Vision.svg'
import Psychotherapist from './Mental_Health.svg'
import NoResultsBgBean from './no_results_bg_bean.svg'
import NoResultsBgCircle from './no_results_bg_circle.svg'
import NoClaims from './noClaims.svg'


export const gscIcons: {
  [index: string]: React.ElementType
} = {
  ['Chiro']: Chiro,
  ['Physio']: Physio,
  ['Massage,']: Massage,
  ['MI']: MI,
  ['Orthodontic']: Orthodontic,
  ['Podiatry']: Podiatry,
  ['Acupuncture']: Acupuncture,
  ['Speech']: Speech,
  ['Chiropody']: Chiropody,
  ['Naturopathy']: Naturopathy,
  ['Psychology']: Psychology,
  ['Dental']: Dental,
  ['Osteopath']: Osteopath,
  ['Audiologist']: Audiologist,
  ['Athletic']: Athletic,
  ['Dietician']: Dietician,
  ['Homeopath']: Homeopath,
  ['Occupational']: Occupational,
  ['Drug']: Drug,
  ['MasterOfSocialWork']: MasterOfSocialWork,
  ['SocialWorker']: SocialWorker,
  ['Vision']: Vision,
  ['Psychotherapist']: Psychotherapist,
  ['member_since']: member_since,
  ['add_claims']: add_claims,
  ['add_claims_inactive']: add_claims_inactive,
  ['select_provider']: select_provider,
  ['select_provider_inactive']: select_provider_inactive,
  ['submit_claim']: submit_claim,
  ['submit_claim_inactive']: submit_claim_inactive,
  ['verify_information']: verify_information,
  ['verify_information_inactive']: verify_information_inactive,
  ['VISION_CAT']: VISION_CAT,
  ['DENTAL_CAT']: DENTAL_CAT,
  ['CHIRO_TREATMENT']: CHIRO_TREATMENT,
  ['DRUG_CAT']: DRUG_CAT,
  ['EMERG_HOSP_HOME_CAT']: EMERG_HOSP_HOME_CAT,
  ['FOOT_CARE_CAT']: FOOT_CARE_CAT,
  ['HEARING_CAT']: HEARING_CAT,
  ['MASSAGE']: MASSAGE,
  ['LAB_TEST_CAT']: LAB_TEST_CAT,
  ['MED_ITEMS_CAT']: MED_ITEMS_CAT,
  ['MENTAL_HEALTH_CAT']: MENTAL_HEALTH_CAT,
  ['OTHER_SPEC_SERV_CAT']: OTHER_SPEC_SERV_CAT,
  ['ACUPUNCTURE']: ACUPUNCTURE,
  ['PHYSIOTHERAPY']: PHYSIOTHERAPY,
  ['SPENDING_CAT']: SPENDING_CAT,
  ['OTHER_SRVCS_CAT']: OTHER_SRVCS_CAT,
  ['accupuncture']: accupuncture,
  ['ambulance']: ambulance,
  ['athletic']: athletic,
  ['blood_monitor']: blood_monitor,
  ['blood_test']: blood_test,
  ['body_brace']: body_brace,
  ['breathing_equipment']: breathing_equipment,
  ['chiropodist']: chiropodist,
  ['counselling']: counselling,
  ['dental_services']: dental_services,
  ['dietician']: dietician,
  ['drug_pill']: drug_pill,
  ['estimate']: estimate,
  ['eye_exam']: eye_exam,
  ['glasses_contacts']: glasses_contacts,
  ['health_care_spending_acct']: health_care_spending_acct,
  ['hearing_aids']: hearing_aids,
  ['hearing_exam']: hearing_exam,
  ['homeopathy']: homeopathy,
  ['hospital_room']: hospital_room,
  ['in_home_nursing']: in_home_nursing,
  ['medical_cannabis']: medical_cannabis,
  ['naturopathy']: naturopathy,
  ['nursing_home_ltc']: nursing_home_ltc,
  ['occupational_therapy']: occupational_therapy,
  ['orthodontics']: orthodontics,
  ['orthotics']: orthotics,
  ['osteopathy']: osteopathy,
  ['other_diagnostic_tests']: other_diagnostic_tests,
  ['other_supplies']: other_supplies,
  ['personal_spending_acct']: personal_spending_acct,
  ['']: podiatrist,
  ['podiatrist']: speech_therapy,
  ['warning']: warning,
  ['x_ray']: x_ray,
  ['other_specialist_services']: other_specialist_services,
  ['filter']: filter,
  ['Icon_Checkbox_Deselected']: Icon_Checkbox_Deselected,
  ['Icon_Checkbox_Selected']: Icon_Checkbox_Selected,
  ['right_chevron']: right_chevron,
  ['question']: question,
  ['dashboard_fill']: dashboard_fill,
  ['dashboard_outline']: dashboard_outline,
  ['claims_fill']: claims_fill,
  ['claims_outline']: claims_outline,
  ['coverage_fill']: coverage_fill,
  ['coverage_outline']: coverage_outline,
  ['profile_fill']: profile_fill,
  ['profile_outline']: profile_outline,
  ['search_fill']: search_fill,
  ['search_outline']: search_outline,
  ['gsc_download']: gsc_download,
  ['payment']: payment,
  ['health_provider']: health_provider,
  ['form']: form,
  ['success']: success,
  ['failure']: failure,
  ['pending']: pending,
  ['approved']: approved,
  ['declined']: declined,
  ['Unknown']: Unknown,
  ['in_progress']: in_progress,
  ['attention']: attention,
  ['coverage_booklet']: coverage_booklet,
  ['NoResultsBgBean']: NoResultsBgBean,
  ['NoResultsBgCircle']: NoResultsBgCircle,
  ['NoClaims']: NoClaims,
default:MED_ITEMS_CAT,

  // not sure what provider categories will map to these graphics / no other provider categories from BE at this time
  // './emergency-hospital-home-care.svg',
  // './medical-imaging.svg',
  // './spending-accounts.svg',
}


// export default {
//   Chiro,
//   Physio,
//   Massage,
//   MI,
//   Orthodontic,
//   Podiatry,
//   Acupuncture,
//   Speech,
//   Chiropody,
//   Naturopathy,
//   Psychology,
//   Dental,
//   Osteopath,
//   Audiologist,
//   Athletic,
//   Dietician,
//   Homeopath,
//   Occupational,
//   Drug,
//   MasterOfSocialWork,
//   SocialWorker,
//   Vision,
//   Psychotherapist,
//   member_since,
//   add_claims,
//   add_claims_inactive,
//   select_provider,
//   select_provider_inactive,
//   submit_claim,
//   submit_claim_inactive,
//   verify_information,
//   verify_information_inactive,
//   VISION_CAT,
//   DENTAL_CAT,
//   CHIRO_TREATMENT,
//   DRUG_CAT,
//   EMERG_HOSP_HOME_CAT,
//   FOOT_CARE_CAT,
//   HEARING_CAT,
//   MASSAGE,
//   LAB_TEST_CAT,
//   MED_ITEMS_CAT,
//   MENTAL_HEALTH_CAT,
//   OTHER_SPEC_SERV_CAT,
//   ACUPUNCTURE,
//   PHYSIOTHERAPY,
//   SPENDING_CAT,
//   OTHER_SRVCS_CAT,
//   accupuncture,
//   ambulance,
//   athletic,
//   blood_monitor,
//   blood_test,
//   body_brace,
//   breathing_equipment,
//   chiropodist,
//   counselling,
//   dental_services,
//   dietician,
//   drug_pill,
//   estimate,
//   eye_exam,
//   glasses_contacts,
//   health_care_spending_acct,
//   hearing_aids,
//   hearing_exam,
//   homeopathy,
//   hospital_room,
//   in_home_nursing,
//   medical_cannabis,
//   naturopathy,
//   nursing_home_ltc,
//   occupational_therapy,
//   orthodontics,
//   orthotics,
//   osteopathy,
//   other_diagnostic_tests,
//   other_supplies,
//   personal_spending_acct,
//   podiatrist,
//   speech_therapy,
//   warning,
//   x_ray,
//   other_specialist_services,
//   filter,
//   Icon_Checkbox_Deselected,
//   Icon_Checkbox_Selected,
//   right_chevron,
//   question,
//   dashboard_fill,
//   dashboard_outline,
//   claims_fill,
//   claims_outline,
//   coverage_fill,
//   coverage_outline,
//   profile_fill,
//   profile_outline,
//   search_fill,
//   search_outline,
//   gsc_download,
//   payment,
//   health_provider,
//   form,
//   success,


GetIcon function is returning number instead of Element.
```